# GoogleApiModule could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, npm-install, google-api-js-client

Tried importing a GoogleApiModule as per the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-gapi, however i've run into the error

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng-gapi/lib/GoogleApiModule.d.ts:2:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

    This likely means that the library (ng-gapi) which declares GoogleApiModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

    2 export declare class GoogleApiModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here's what I tried:
(in app.module.ts)

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    GoogleApiModule.forRoot({
      provide: NG_GAPI_CONFIG,
      useValue: gapiClientConfig
    })
```

I also attempted to just reference the `ngModule` member of the returned `ModuleWithProviders<GoogleApiModule>` from `GoogleApiModule.forRoot()`, which also yielded errors.

Is there any way to inject this service?

Note: I *also* attempted to set `"enableIvy": false` in `tsconfig.json`, once again to no avail (and it also gave new errors).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by disabling both AOT *and* ivy.

in tsconfig.json:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

in package.json:

```
"build": {
.
.
.
    "aot": false,
.
.
```

Comment: Getting rid of an Angular service upgrade like Ivy shouldn't be the best solution.